# qsort() sorts one array of strings but segfaults on another one

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, qsort

I'm trying to read a bunch of names from a .txt file and copying them to an array as I go.  I then want to sort the array using qsort().  Also, the file I'm reading is names.txt from [Project Euler #22](http://projecteuler.net/problem=22).  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* create a pointer to point to s */
char *strdup(char *s)
{
    char *p;

    p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    if (p != NULL)
    strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *ap = *(const char **) a;
    const char *bp = *(const char **) b;
    return strcmp(ap, bp);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int c, i, j=0;
    char name[100], *names[10000];

    fp = fopen("names.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("can't open file\n");
    exit(0);
    }

    c = fgetc(fp); /* initialize c and skip first quotation mark */

    while (c != EOF) { /* loop until no names are left */
    i = 0;
    while ((c=fgetc(fp)) != '"') /* copy chars to name until " is reached */
        name[i++] = c;
    name[i] = '\0';
    names[j++] = strdup(name);
    fgetc(fp); /* skip comma */
    c = fgetc(fp);
    }

    size_t size  = sizeof(names[0]);
    size_t count = sizeof(names)/size;
    qsort((void **) names, count, size, &compare);

    return 0;

}
```

Trying to sort the names array causes a segfault.  However, if I instead try to sort an array of strings that is explicitly declared it works:

```
char *test[] = { "FOO", "BAR", "TEST" };

size_t size  = sizeof(test[0]);
size_t count = sizeof(test)/size;
qsort((void **) test, count, size, &compare);

for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", test[i]);

return 0;
```

I suspect that the segfault is due to an error in my array "names", but if I loop through and print each element of "names" before trying to sort it does so without a problem.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
size_t count = sizeof(names)/size;
```

Will yield the *entire* length of your `names` array, not just the values you have initialized.  If you entered fewer than 10000 names, you're going to have some invalid pointers in there, and when you try to sort them - KABOOM!

You can just use `j` instead of `count`, since you're using that to keep track of how many names have been input.

Comment: Replacing count with j worked like a charm!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to initialise `names`.

The easiest way to do so is like this:

```
names[10000] = {NULL};
```

Also the compare function is not prepared to handle the unused entries, you could modify it like this, treating unused entries like emtpy entries.

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const char *ap = a ?*(const char **) a :"";
  const char *bp = b ?*(const char **) b :"";

  return strcmp(ap, bp);
}
```

Alternativly you could sort all unused entries to the end:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  if (*a && *b)
  {
    const char *ap = a ?*(const char **) a :"";
    const char *bp = b ?*(const char **) b :"";

    return strcmp(ap, bp);
  }
  else
  {
    if (*a)
      return -1;
    else (*b)
      return 1;

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Also you are telling `qsort()` to always inspect all of `names`'s entries. Which is is unnecessary.

Comment: Why would you want to sort unused entries to the end?  They already *are* at the end. Given that, why even initialize them at all?

Comment: @CarlNorum: For fun ...? S-) ... - no, to be serious: There might be the use case that they hadn't had been assigned sequentially.